# how to use a swing timer to start/stop animation

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, applet

Could someone teach me how to use a `swing timer` with the following purpose:

I need to have a polygon that begins being animated(simple animation such as rotating) when I click the mouse; and stops animating when I click again.

I do not have problems understanding the way the `MouseListener` works, but with the actual animation. I tried simulating the animation with a while block inside the `paint()` method where I would draw, erase and redraw the polygon(to simulate a rotation for example), but inside the while, the applet would not listen to the clicks. It would listen only after the while. I would need the swing timer to break the while when I click the mouse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
```

Add an attribute;

```
Timer timer; 
boolean b;   // for starting and stoping animation
```

Add the following code to frame's constructor.

```
timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        // change polygon data
        // ...

        repaint();
    }
});
```

Override `paint(Graphics g)` and draw polygon from the data that was modified by `actionPerformed(e)`.

Finally, a button that start/stop animation has the following code in its event handler.

```
if (b) {
    timer.start();
} else {
    timer.stop();
}
b = !b;
```

Comment: Sorry if my questions will seem stupid, but what do you mean by frame's constructor ( is it the init() method). Also where do I implement the button(event handler). Thank you

Comment: The constructor of a class is a method that has the same name as the class.  For example, the class `public MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame` has `public MyFrame() { ... }` as its constructor. The constructor will be called when we create the object using `new` keyword. For example, a frame object can be created using this command `MyFrame f = new MyFrame();`

Comment: Ok I understand, but I don't see where do I have a frame constructor in a class that extends java applet. I added the new timer to the init() method, but it doesn't seem to work right. The applet respons to clicks, but it seems that the polygon data doesn't get changed.

Comment: If you use Applet, you can put the code `timer = new Timer...` in the `init()` method. No need to create a constructor. BTW, have you overrided `public void paint( Graphics g )` to paint the polygon?

Comment: I have put the code timer = new Timer... in the init() method. In the paint method i have something like if coordonates of the mouse click are on the polygon then{ timer.start(); drawPolygon;}. Is it ok if i put timer.start() in the paint() method?

Comment: `paint(g)` should contain just drawing code such as `g.drawLine(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series/5048863#5048863) controls a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) using a button, while this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405799/how-to-rotate-an-image-gradually-in-swing/3420651#3420651) responds to a mouse click. The latter example reverses direction on each click, but *start/stop* is a straightforward alteration.

Answer (score 1):

The applet won't listen to clicks because the main thread (the Event Dispatch Thread, EDT) is within the while-loop and isn't listening to your clicks.

You need another thread. 
(try using SwingWorker http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

So, the SwingWorker will do the while-loop in the background, publishing results to make your polygon move.

And the EDT can then focus on any events (like clicks). You can then just use the click-event to kill the SwingWorker if you want to stop it.

Good luck