# Java Graphics Updating Too Fast

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics

I have searched the problem, but everyone seems to have problems with graphics updating too slow.

To present my situation:

I have a JFrame which I set to full screen, by using a compatible display mode.
Within the JFrame I have a couple of JPanels and JButtons...
On one of JPanels I am drawing moving objects that need to be updated.

I am updating the graphics like this : validate and repaint the JFrame, then revalidate and repaint the corresponding JPanel. 
The graphics are updating too fast. (I need to mention that on the JPanel I am overriding the paintComponent method).
I have tried to use BufferStrategy on the JFrame, however this will prevent me from showing the JPanels and JButtons (have no idea why).

I also take this oppurtunity to ask some of you guys if you can give a clear distinction between paint, validate, repaint, revalidate, invalidate, etc... all the tutorials barely scratch the surface.

Comment: You only need to revalidate when a component as been added/removed from its parent. It has nothing to do with painting. Please explain what you're trying to do, and show an attempt or at least what you have so far

Comment: Can you explain why you think it is updating too fast?

Comment: The reason I think it is updating too fast is because if I use a normally defined JFrame (new JFrame, and not a full screen one with a display mode) it works normally (I have some balls moving in a labirint).
The code looks like this :
void rollBalls(){
f.validate();
f.repaint();
updateBallsSpecs();
p.revalidate();
p.repaint();}


f is the JFrame and p is the JPanel within the JFrame. The update specs method simply updates the specification of the balls (coordinates in an array), coordinates which I use in the paintComponent method within the JPanel class.

Comment: What kind of timing mechanism are you using for your animation? Please show some code

Comment: The timing mechanism is simply a loop that runs for 5 minutes using System.timeCurrentMillis to count that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The timing mechanism is simply a loop that runs for 5 minutes using System.timeCurrentMillis to count that"

That's not going to work. The loop is ultimately blocking the painting to occur until the loop is complete, if there is no delay.

I suggest you look into using a `javax.swing.Timer` for the animation. You can see more at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

The basic construct of `Timer` is as follows

```
Timer ( int delayInMillis, ActionListener listener )
```

where `delayInMillis` is the time in milliseconds to delay between *"ticks"* and the `listener` provides the `actionPerformed` which is called every `delayInMillis` milliseconds. So ultimately you do something like

```
Timer timer = new Timer (40, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (Ball ball: balls) {
            ball.move();
            repaint();
        }
    }
});
```

---

You can see a complete example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22283611/2587435)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but on which should I call repaint, on the JFrame or JPanel inside JFrame?

Comment: If you are painting on the panel, then call repaint on the panel. See the example I linked

Comment: Thank you it works. I updated the JFrame or the Jpanel since it's the same (Jpanel is a child of my JFrame), i just lose a bit on the fps side.

Comment: Well, 1000 milliseconds in a second, so 40 milliseconds delay mean fps = 1000/40 = 25 :-)